# In CKEditor 5, can I create a new "restricted-editing-exception" span element with writer.createElement?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

### Update: I solved it with a different method. See my comment below.

I am looking to programatically grab a block of text, modify it, and re-insert it into a "restricted-editing-exception" element in the editor with a custom plugin. The closest I can get is inserting text into a

element beneath the original  element.

The most relevant bit of code:

```js
editor.model.change(writer => {

                            const position = writer.createPositionAt(parentBlock, block.index);
                            const newElement = writer.createElement(parentBlock.name, parentBlock.getAttributes());

                        
                            writer.remove(block);
                            writer.insert(newElement, position);
                            block = newElement;
                        
                            writer.insertText(textChunk, block, 0);
                            firstChunk = false;
                        }
                         else {
                            // Insert the rest of the chunks at the end of the block
                            writer.insertText(textChunk, block, 'end');
                        }
```

And here is the original HTML before running the command:

```html
<p><strong>Topic</strong>:&nbsp;</p>
<p><span class="restricted-editing-exception">Define the topic.</span></p>
<p><strong>Articles</strong>:&nbsp;</p>
<p><span class="restricted-editing-exception">Define your articles</span></p>
<p><strong>Other things</strong>:&nbsp;</p>
```

And here's how it looks after I run the command:

```html
<p><strong>Topic</strong>:&nbsp;</p>
<p><span class="restricted-editing-exception">Define the topic.</span></p>
<p><strong>Articles</strong>:&nbsp;</p>
<p><span class="restricted-editing-exception restricted-editing-exception_collapsed"></span><p>{{HERE IS THE INSERTED CONTENT}}</p><strong>Other Things</strong>:&nbsp;</p>
```

In model.change I can confirm that parentBlock is the

tag. If I try to get the child of that block (in the plugin config.ts code), it does not return an element, it's just a text field. So I can't use that "child" to writer.createElement.

`const newElement = writer.createElement('span', { 'restrictedEditingException': true });`

didn't work either.

Been messing around for hours, would love any suggestions!

Comment: If anyone ends up here in the future, here's how I solved it:
Instead of trying to replace the entire block, my plugin selected all the text in the block from wherever the cursor is, deleted it, then filled in the text that I wanted. In this way, the text stays within the span.